# Source variable for the categorisation does not exist

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-wrangling, factors

I am trying to create a factor variable from a newly created variable that counts the number of items across multiple columns. I am currently having issues with the final stage, this is when I try to categorise the new variable, here R tells me that the source variable for the categorisation does not exist when it does. Could anyone help me with this problem? The source and the error code are hared below. Many thanks in advance.

```
# download pacman package if not installed, otherwise load it
if (!require(pacman)) install.packages(pacman)

# loads relevant packages using the pacman package
pacman::p_load(
  tidyverse,  
  data.table) 


# Create dataset
data <- data.table(A = sample(as.numeric(c(0, 1, 2)), 1300,replace = TRUE),
                   B = sample(as.numeric(c(0, 0, 2)), 1300,replace = TRUE),
                   C = sample(as.numeric(c(0, 1, 2)), 1300,replace = TRUE),
                   D = sample(as.numeric(c(0, 0, 1)), 1300,replace = TRUE),
                   E = sample(as.numeric(c(0, 1, 1)), 1300,replace = TRUE))  


# sum up all of the relevant rows and create new sumVar column
data <- data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(sumVar = sum(c_across((B:E)))) 

# categorise the newly created sum variable
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(sum = 9) %>% 
  .[sumVar == 0, sum := 1] %>% 
  .[sumVar == 1, sum := 2] %>% 
  .[sumVar == 2, sum := 3] %>% 
  .[sumVar >= 3, sum := 4] %>% 
  .[sum == 9, sum := NA]
```

Error produced from the above code....

```
Error in `[.tbl_df`(., sumVar == 0, `:=`(sum, 1)) : 
  object 'sumVar' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `rowwise` your data is no longer `data.table` but a tibble, so `data.table` syntax would not work on it. Try -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

data %>%
  .[sumVar == 0, sum := 1] %>% 
  .[sumVar == 1, sum := 2] %>% 
  .[sumVar == 2, sum := 3] %>% 
  .[sumVar >= 3, sum := 4] %>% 
  .[sum == 9, sum := NA] 

data

#      A B C D E sumVar sum
#   1: 2 0 1 1 0      2   3
#   2: 1 2 2 0 0      4   4
#   3: 1 0 2 1 1      4   4
#   4: 0 0 0 0 1      1   2
#   5: 1 2 0 1 1      4   4
#  ---                     
#1296: 1 2 1 0 1      4   4
#1297: 2 0 0 0 0      0   1
#1298: 2 0 2 0 1      3   4
#1299: 0 2 1 0 0      3   4
#1300: 2 2 0 0 1      3   4
```